# using if statement in each-loop

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a loop

```
<% _.each(kw, function (x) { %>
```

now I want to use a if statement which checks a string

```
<% if ( <%=x%> == "condition") { %>
    <div>..</div>
<% } %>
```

but doesn't work :( any ideas?

---

another question:

```
<script>     
   var maxKW = $("[id^='kalenderwoche']:first").attr("id");    
</script>
```

is declared above and what would be the correct if statement when I want to use maxKW

```
<% if ( <%=x%> == maxKW) { %>
    <div>..</div>
<% } %>
```

would be great if you could help me :)

Comment: What is `<%` and `%>`?

Comment: tags to wrap javascript syntax

Comment: @Tomalak http://underscorejs.org/#template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% if (x === "condition") { %>
    <div>..</div>
<% } %>
```

---

Pass `maxKW` as attribute to the compiled template:

```
var maxKW = $("[id^='kalenderwoche']:first").attr("id");  
var html = _.template('your html')({maxKW:maxKW});
```

Comment: thx for your answer. Isn't there a way to do sth. like this: <% if (x == $("[id^='kalenderwoche']:first").attr("id")) { %>

Comment: Yes, it would work. But it is not recommended way. `<% var maxKW = $("[id^='kalenderwoche']:first").attr("id"); %><% if (x === maxKW) print('it works') %>`